# finding a file extension in terminal and cmd

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, terminal, scripting

so I'm making a chrome extention that will create either a .bat or a .sh file that will run some code, however one of the problems is that I need it to test for a file that has a particular extension, example

```
cd 01 && rm *.part&& if(test for a file extention in the working dir) === true {code} && cd.. && cd 02
```

and so on and so on, I need to test for a .flv file, so can I have an example for either a cross-platform (like how mkdir is in both cmd and Unix) or an example for both of them.

Comment: If this would be able that would be so bad, imagine a chrome extension being able to execute `del` or another command like that on your computer

Comment: no, it's not going to do that, its just going to create a .bat or a .sh file, sorry if the text is confusing

Comment: I know it's not going to do that, but if you could execute commands that can create files, you can delete files. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A Chrome extension is code fed to the browser and executed within the browser.

Source: [Chrome extension APIs index](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html)

Comment: even if the chrome extension just displays the code so I can then coppy and paste the code into either terminal or command prompt that would be enough, I just need to know how to test for any file that contains the .flv extension in the working directory

Comment: The command `find ./ -iname *.flv` will do just that. But that has nothing to do with a chrome extension.